# Identifying when long running async tasks have completed

Tags: c#, async-await

[Updated 18-Apr-2018 with LinqPad example - see end]

My application receives a list of jobs:

```
var jobs = await myDB.GetWorkItems();
```

(NB: we use .ConfigureAwait(false) everwhere, I'm just not showing it in these pseudo code snippets.)

For each job, we create a long running Task.  However, we don't want to wait for this long running Task to complete.

```
jobs.ForEach(job =>
{
    var module = Factory.GetModule(job.Type);
    var task = Task.Run(() => module.ExecuteAsync(job.Data));
    this.NonAwaitedTasks.Add(task, module);
};
```

The task and its related module instance are both added to a ConcurrentDictionary so that they don't go out of scope.

Elsewhere, I have another method that is called occasionally which contains the following:

```
foreach (var entry in this.NonAwaitedTasks.Where(e => e.Key.IsCompleted))
{
    var module = entry.Value as IDisposable;
    module?.Dispose();
    this.NonAwaitedTasks.Remove(entry.Key);
}
```

(NB the NonAwaitedTasks is additionally locked using a SemaphoreSlim...)

So, the idea is that this method will find all those Tasks which have completed and then dispose of their related module, and remove them from this Dictionary.

However....

Whilst debugging in Visual Studio 2017, I pull a single job from the DB and whilst I'm taking my time debugging within the single Module that has been instantiated, the Dispose is called on that module.  Looking in the Callstack, I can see the Dispose has been called in the method above, and that is because the task has IsCompleted == true.  But evidently, it can't be completed because I'm still debugging it.

- Is the .IsCompleted property the wrong property to check?
- Is this just an artifact of debugging in Visual Studio?
- Am I going about this the wrong way?

**Additional Information**

In the comments below, I was asked to provide some additional information regarding the flow because what I described didn't seem possible (and indeed, my hope was that it couldn't be).  Below is a cut-down version of my code (I've removed checks for the cancellation token and defensive coding, but nothing that affects the flow).

**Application Entry Point**

This is a Windows Service.  In the OnStart() is the following line:

```
this.RunApplicationTask = 
Task.Run(() => myApp.DoWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false), myService.CancelSource.Token);
```

"RunApplicationTask" is just a property to keep the executing task in scope during the lifetime of the Service.

**DoWorkAsync()**

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    do
    {
        await this.ExecuteSingleIterationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    while (myApp.ServiceCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false);

    await Task.WhenAll(this.NonAwaitedTasks.Keys).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await this.ClearCompletedTasksAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    this.WorkItemsTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);

    return;
}
```

So whilst I'm debugging, this is iterating the DO-LOOP, it does not get to the Task.WhenAll(....).

Note too that after the Cancellation request is called and all Tasks have completed, I call ClearCompletedTasksAsync().  More on that later....

**ExecuteSingleIterationAsync**

```
private async Task ExecuteSingleIterationAsync()
{
    var getJobsResponse = await DB.GetJobsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await this.ProcessWorkLoadAsync(getJobsResponse.Jobs).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await this.ClearCompletedTasksAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

**ProcessWorkLoadAsync**

```
private async Task ProcessWorkLoadAsync(IList<Job> jobs)
{
    if (jobs.NoItems())
    {
        return ;
    }

    jobs.ForEach(job =>
    {
        // The processor instance is disposed of when removed from the NonAwaitedTasks collection.
        IJobProcessor processor = ProcessorFactory.GetProcessor(workItem, myApp.ServiceCancellationToken);
        try
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => processor.ExecuteAsync(job).ConfigureAwait(false), myApp.ServiceCancellationToken);
            this.NonAwaitedTasks.Add(task, processor);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
        }
    });

    return;
}
```

Each processor implements the following interface method:
**Task ExecuteAsync(Job job);**

It's whilst I'm in the ExecuteAsync that .Dispose() gets called on the processor instance I'm using.

**ProcessorFactory.GetProcessor()**

```
public static IJobProcessor GetProcessor(Job job, CancellationToken token)
{
    .....
    switch (someParamCalculatedAbove)
    {
        case X:
            {
                return new XProcessor(...);
            }

        case Y:
            {
                return new YProcessor(...);
            }

        default:
            {
                return null;
            }
    }
}
```

So here we're getting a **new** instance.

**ClearCompletedTasksAsync()**

```
private async Task ClearCompletedTasksAsync()
{
    await myStatic.NonAwaitedTasksPadlock.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    try
    {
        foreach (var taskEntry in this.NonAwaitedTasks.Where(entry => entry.Key.IsCompleted).ToArray())
        {
            var processorInstance = taskEntry.Value as IDisposable;
            processorInstance?.Dispose();
            this.NonAwaitedTasks.Remove(taskEntry.Key);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        myStatic.NonAwaitedTasksPadlock.Release();
    }
}
```

This is called every iteration of the Do-Loop.  It's purpose is to ensure that the list of non-awaited tasks is kept small.

And that's it...  Dispose only seems to get called when debugging.

**LinqPad example**

```
async Task Main()
{
    SetProcessorRunning();

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    do
    {
        foreach (var entry in NonAwaitedTasks.Where(e => e.Key.IsCompleted).ToArray())
        {
            "Task is completed, so will dispose of the Task's processor...".Dump();
            var p = entry.Value as IDisposable;
            p?.Dispose();
            NonAwaitedTasks.Remove(entry.Key);
        }
    }
    while (NonAwaitedTasks.Count > 0);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public void SetProcessorRunning()
{
    var p = new Processor();

    var task = Task.Run(() => p.DoWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
    NonAwaitedTasks.Add(task, p);
}

public interface IProcessor
{
    Task DoWorkAsync();
}

public static Dictionary<Task, IProcessor> NonAwaitedTasks = new Dictionary<Task, IProcessor>();

public class Processor : IProcessor, IDisposable
{
    bool isDisposed = false;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.isDisposed = true;
        "I have been disposed of".Dump();
    }

    public async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (this.isDisposed)
        {
            $"I have been disposed of (isDispose = {this.isDisposed}) but I've not finished work yet...".Dump();
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Task is completed, so will dispose of the Task's processor...
>
> I have been disposed of
>
> I have been disposed of (isDispose = True) but I've not finished work
>   yet...

Comment: Side note: naming presumably synchronous method `ExecuteAsync` with `...Async` suffix is very confusing. Please make sure to not do that at least for public samples you showing here (aka [MCVE]).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov’s point might point at the actual issue too. Is Module.ExecuteAsync() actually an async method? If that’s the case then Task.Run() _will_ complete before ExecuteAsync() completes (assuming you have any awaits in ExecuteAsync()).

Comment: The task won't be marked as complete until it's complete, so what you're describing isn't possible. There must be something else going on, e.g., another job with the same `Type` (and therefore the same module), or an `async void`, or fire-and-forget code.

Comment: Stephen is correct; I was (mis-)thinking of the `Task` constructor, where your lambda might look like a function but is actually an action, so ignore my comment above.  I think you need to show us the signature of `ExecuteAsync()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far.  I've added a lot more detail to the original post.

Comment: Try getting rid of all of the `Task.Run`s and just working with the `Task`s that your methods return. Most good async code contains few, if any, `Task.Run`s, especially just to call methods that already return `Task`.

Comment: @Damien.  It's not that simple.  I have a tight loop that pulls the workload from the DB and sets lots of long running tasks executing.  It doesn't want to hang around waiting for these to complete, but go to the DB and see if there's any more work to do.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary.  I've edited my post to include a cut-down LinqPad script which demonstrates this.  Hopefully it's clear to someone what my mistake is...

Comment: @DrGriff `Task.Run` isn't necessary to not await a task. To not await a task you can just not await it, even if you don't schedule a thread pool thread to start the asynchronous operation for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => p.DoWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
```

Hover over the `var` and take a look at what type that is.

`Task.Run` understands `async` delegates by having special "task unwrapping" rules for `Func<Task<Task>>` and friends. But it won't have any special unwrapping for `Func<ConfiguredTaskAwaitable>`.

You can think of it this way; with the code above:

1. `p.DoWorkAsync()` returns a `Task`.
2. `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)` returns a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`.
3. So the `Task.Run` is being asked to run this function that creates a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` on a thread pool thread.
4. Thus, the return type of `Task.Run` is `Task<ConfiguredTaskAwaitable>` - a task that completes as soon as the `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` is created. When it is *created* - not when it completes.

In this case, the `ConfigureAwait(false)` isn't doing anything anyway, because there's no `await` to configure. So you can remove it:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => p.DoWorkAsync());
```

Also, as Servy mentioned, if you don't *need* to run `DoWorkAsync` on a thread pool thread, you can also skip the `Task.Run`:

```
var task = p.DoWorkAsync();
```

Comment: Stephen Cleary and Servy both method that I could ditch the Task.Run if I don't need to run my task on a thread pool thread.  Mine is a Windows Service that implements a loop that first gets n-number of work items from the DB, then sets each work item processing (asynchronously as they involve i/o) in a fire-and-forget manner, and then performs another iteration of the loop.  In this case, I think the async fire-and-forget should be on thread poop threads.  Would you concur?

Comment: I almost never recommend fire-and-forget. Are you absolutely sure that you want exceptions to be silently swallowed?

Comment: Understood.  In this case though the async method that is called in a "fire and forget" way is self-contained; it does a variety of actions, handles exceptions and logs state to the DB so nothing is silently swallowed.  There's nothing to "report back" - we only want to keep tags on the Task so that the Service can't stop until it's completed.  I think this therefore should be a thread pool thread...

Comment: "so that the Service can't stop until it's completed" - this is another reason I don't recommend fire-and-forget. If you were keeping the `Task`s, then you could `await` on them during shutdown. That just seems cleaner to me than "keeping tags". To put another way, you *already have* a signal (the `Task`) that notifies you when the background task is complete; why build another one?

Comment: That's kinda what we are doing.  The async method executed on the Task is self contained (as described above).  It has nothing to return when it's completed.  We do though add the task to the dictionary (this.NonAwaitedTasks) and periodically remove all those tasks that have completed.  The only purpose of this dictionary is so that when someone clicks [STOP] we then await a WHENALL on those remaining tasks.  So it's effectively "fire-and-forget-unless-someone-clicks-STOP".  But the question remains, should I use Task.Run(...) to specifically run these from the thread pool?

Comment: Sure, that's fine. `Task.Run` is nice to offload everything to the thread pool and not block the calling code at all. If you don't ignore the task from the `Task.Run`, then it's not really fire-and-forget at all.